# How to check that Excel cell contains REF! error in VBA

Tags: vba, ref

I found many discussions on how to do it in Excel, but my goal is to capture REF! error in VBA, not in Excel itself. Is it possible ?

Comment: It will contain an error value. e.g. activecell.Value =
Error 2042 for #N/A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
If IsError(cell.Value) Then
    If cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrName) Then
        ...
    End If
End If
```

---

The original code is wrong and will give a Type Mismatch error if the cell does not contain an error.

```
If cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: what happens if `cell` is empty?

Comment: @MikeD I have no idea why I did not respond to that three years ago (probably missed a notification), but you are correct, it would blow not only on empty cells, but also on cells with any non-error contents.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub CheckRef()
Dim CheckRange As Range, CheckCell As Range

    Set CheckRange = [A1:D10]                ' as per app

    For Each CheckCell In CheckRange
    If IsError(CheckCell) And _
       CVErr(CheckCell) = CVErr(2023) Then ' 2023 --> xlErrRef
            MsgBox ("#REF! in  " & CheckCell.AddressLocal)
            Exit Sub                     ' exit after first #REF! found
        End If
    Next CheckCell
End Sub
```

example

- enter "=1/0" in B2 to create an error different to "#REF!"
- enter 1 in B4, B5
- enter "=B4+B5" in B7
- delete row 4
- run `Sub CheckRef()`

[image]

Comment: What happens if `CheckCell` contains the number `2023`?

Comment: ahh ... clever question ... thanks for pointing out ... in that case we're detecting a false positive ... so we have to add a check for `IsError(CheckCell)` ... changing answer