# Range with variable in row and columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check text in a range of cells, Columns A to L and Rows 2 to 10, I want to use a for to go through that range, but I get an error

```
For x = 1 To 12 Step 1
 For i = 2 To 10 Step 1
    If Range(x, i).Value = "#REF!" Then
     Range(x, i) = "0"
    End If
   Next
 Next
```

Comment: To replace any error value (not just `#REF!`), you could do `Range("A2:L10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Value = "0"`. Also, you could use this to loop through fewer cells to find the `#REF!` values: `Set srg = Range("A2:L10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` and continue with a loop `For Each sCell in srg.Cells`... and apply BigBen's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues:

- Use `Cells` instead of `Range`.
- [Test if the cell contains a #REF! error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717509/how-to-check-that-excel-cell-contains-ref-error-in-vba)

```
For x = 1 To 12 Step 1
    For i = 2 To 10 Step 1
        If IsError(Cells(x, i).Value) Then
            If Cells(x, i).Value = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then
                Cells(x, i).Value = 0 '<--- no quotes, write a number not a string
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use numerical loop, you can use structure like this, if you want to detect all #REF errors and replace them with zero.

```
Sub test()
    Dim itm As Variant
    For Each itm In Range("A2:L10")
        If IsError(itm.Value) Then
            If itm.Value = CVErr(xlErrName) Then itm.Value = 0
        End If
    Next itm
End Sub
```

Comment: Although this is working, you should remove possible confusion by rather using something like `Dim Cell As Range`˙, `For Each Cell In Range("A2:L10").Cells` and replace the remaining occurrences of `itm` with `Cell`. A rule of thumb would be: *use `Variant` if no other way*. Re-read MS Docs' [For Each...Next statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) (the *element* part).